# Query on absolute positioning of an element

Tags: html, css

Below is the html code,

```
<div class="simple">
    <nav class="fancy">
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Below is the css code,

```
div, nav{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.simple{
    max-width: 400px;
    position: relative;

}

.fancy{
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Why does absolute positioning of `nav` element makes the height of `div` element zero?

Comment: As far as I know `overflow:hidden;` or something similar on the `<div>` solves this. It’s basically because the `<nav>` is on a different layer and no longer affects the `<div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of normal flow. Only elements in normal flow are counted when calculating the (auto) height of their parents. When you remove *fancy* there are no longer any elements in normal flow inside *simple*, so its computed height becomes `0`.

Comment: Do you mean, `nav` element with absolute positioning is actually not a child element of `div`?

Comment: @overexchange the answer is pretty clear, nav is under div with no doubt. Because nav is set to position absolute, it's out of the normal flow (in the other words we can also say it's removed from div), and there nothing else under the div, it collapses to nothing.

Comment: @Pangloss Problem is, if I set `top`&`left` properties to `fancy` element, it is suppose to sit in top-left of first ancestor(in this case `simple` element). Am I correct? But it does not work. This [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vznwuu5r/) works, because `img` element sits right-bottom to `p`. Can you please clarify the problem in my code?

Comment: @overexchange I guess your question is, why the container didn't collapse on your image+text example, it's because the plain text (which is not set to absolute) is holding the space to prevent to height to become 0, the size of the container is exactly the size of the text.

Comment: @Pangloss in this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ssa4gwbz/), nav element does not sit on top-left of its first ancestor I.e., div element. Please help me understand

Comment: @overexchange it is top-left to me, but only 10px away, also see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mwx1s5a6/)

Comment: @Pangloss In your example, `br` tag produces a line. In my example, why `nav` tag is not producing the block that can hold the space? I mean, every single html element is a block of pixels

Comment: @overexchange we've explained that already, suggest to read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) docs to figure it out.

Comment: @overexchange — The nav element is absolutely positioned (so not in normal flow). The br element is statically positioned (the default) so it is in normal flow. The height of the container is calculated based on the height of the br elements (ignoring the height of the nav element entirely).

Comment: @Quentin True, in this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/msxq97ms/1/), height of the container is calculated based on the `br` elements but why the width of `div` has gone zero? Main idea of this code was to check whether absolute child  was positioned within absolute parent.

Comment: @overexchange — Because, if there are no properties with otherwise effect the width, the width of an absolutely positioned element is calculated from its (normal flow) content, and line breaks don't have a width.

Comment: @Quentin From this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/o5kp54mg/1/), Can I say that, not only absolutely positioned elements but all their descendant will be out of flow?

Comment: The children of an absolutely positioned element will be in normal flow for that element and will be used to calculate the dimensions of their absolutely positioned parent (but not the absolutely positioned element's parent).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.simple` collapses when there is "nothing" inside. Basically, if you don't have any content in the `<div>`, the height becomes zero. To override this you should use a `min-height` parameter e.g.

```
.simple{
    max-width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

a 100px is just an example. You can use a % as well. 
Here working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arcsn/c6my0yva/

Comment: In my code, Are you saying `nav` element is not child of `div` element? If yes, why `nav` element is not a child of `div`? What makes absolute positioning of `nav` element not a child of `div` ekement?

Comment: As far as I know, the absolutely positioned elements are positioning themselves in relation to the body element instead of their direct parent... because they position themselves against the first ancestor that is not static postitioned. That is why your `.simple` colapses, as it becames "empty".

Comment: First ancestor of `nav` element is `div` element, because the position is relative(non-static). Please check the code above.

Comment: When using an element that is relatively positioned and has absolutely positioned elements inside of it, the absolutely positioned child elements are taken out of the normal flow of the parent container and the parent element renders “empty”. it's height is zero and il collapses.

Comment: In dom tree nav is child of div but in browser output it is out of flow. So, when do we think of absolute positioning of element?